# Shortcut for calling first function parameter with rest parameters

Tags: javascript

What is the most concise yet intent-revealing syntax (if any) for `(first, ...rest) => first(...rest)`?

Answers using lodash welcome

EDIT Alternatively, I'm looking for a way of zipping two arrays by calling the functions in the first array with the corresponding elements from the second one, i.e. trying to combine `a = [f1, f2, f3], b = [x1, x2, x3]` into `[f1(x1), f2(x2), f3(x3)]`. Is there a simpler way of doing that than `_.zipWith(a, b, (first, ...rest) => first(...rest))`?

Comment: Can you go into more detail as to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If there exists a method like `_.callFirstParamWithRestParams` - ideally, an answer featuring that. If not - some approximation. I'm using the construct I posted as a lodash reducer for `_.zipWith` and was wondering if there was a more declarative, intent-revealing version

Answer (score 0):

This accomplishes what you want concisely, but not necessarily intent-revealing:

```
a.map((f, i) => f(b[i]))
```

```js
const double = n => n * 2;
const triple = n => n * 3;
const quadruple = n => n * 4;

const a = [double, triple, quadruple];
const b = [5, 10, 15];

console.log(a.map((f, i) => f(b[i])));
```